# A problem with segmented file write

Tags: c#

I download a file's parts (a picture), and then I want to save these parts into one file.

The problem is, that the first part is being downloaded and saved properly (I can see the part of that pricture). But, when the second part is saved (FileMode.Append) the picture seems to be broken.

Here's the code:

```
  HttpWebRequest webRequest;
  HttpWebResponse webResponse;
  Stream responseStream;
  long StartPosition, EndPosition;

        if (File.Exists(LocalPath))
            fileStream = new FileStream(LocalPath, FileMode.Append);
        else fileStream = new FileStream(LocalPath, FileMode.Create);

        webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(FileURL);

        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
        responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StartPosition = 0;   //download first 52062 bytes of the file
        EndPosition = 52061;

        webRequest.AddRange(StartPosition, EndPosition);

        int SeekPosition = (int)StartPosition;

        while ((bytesSize = responseStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            lock (fileStream)
            {
                fileStream.Seek(SeekPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                fileStream.Write(Buffer,0, bytesSize);
            }

  //the Buffer.Length is 2048.
  //When the bytes count to download is < 2048 then I decrease the Buffer.Length
  //to prevent downloading more that 52062 bytes.

            DownloadedBytesCount += bytesSize;
            SeekPosition += bytesSize;

            long TotalToDownload = EndPosition - StartPosition;

            long bytesLeft = TotalToDownload - DownloadedBytesCount;

            if (bytesLeft < Buffer.Length)
                Buffer = new byte[bytesLeft];
        }
```

WHen I want to download the second part of the file I set

```
    StartPosition = 52062;
    EndPosition = 104122;
```

and then there is a problem that I described above. Why the file is not appened properly ?

Comment: What does "seems to be broken" mean?  Don't use FileMode.Append.

Comment: when I try to open that picture after write the 2nd part, I don't see its content.

Comment: Your code is so wrong I don't even know where to start. Why do you need to download the file in parts at all?

Comment: 'cuz I want to develop the file download manager

Comment: This code is wicked... sorry but you must start by deleting all the code and looking at your problem from the beginning. There are many better ways to accomplish what you want. Just take a look at some good solutions: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx

Comment: Just to link them, here is [Part 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `StartPosition`, `fileStream.Seek()` and `Buffer = new byte[bytesLeft];`

Also the `lock()` shouldn't be necessary (if it is you've got a lot more troubles).

So remove all that because the chances are you got some of it wrong.

And if it then still doesn't work, edit the question and provide more information. There is quite a lot missing right now:

- could you verify with the debugger if the download loop is executed at all.
- how is the changeover to the 2nd range 52k - 104k performed
- how long is the resulting file in the end?
- does the file contain the first 52k bytes or the 2nd download?
- etc

All of that matters and we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: I need the Seek operation and lock because the local file will be accessed by many threads. I saw that - what is strange - the 2nd part of the file has the same first 4096 bytes as the 1st part. I know that the server supports Range header because the 1st part is downloaded properly

Comment: If you really use the FileStream (not: file) in different threads you can't use Append mode.

Comment: Ok, so I can change it to FileMode.Open

Answer (score 0):

What i would try is to download the image some way that you know that it works and compare the byte result to check where the file gets broken and what is breaking it...

Answer (score 0):

This code is wicked... sorry but you must start by deleting all the code and looking at your problem from the beginning. There are many better ways to accomplish what you want. Just take a look at some good solutions: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/MyDownloader.aspx